# Oracle SQL 11g get the newest of each category

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using the following table. I need to get the newest `date_joined` of each `DEPT`.

```
 __________________________________
| DEPT     | DATE_JOINED | MANAGER |
|----------------------------------|
|  Produce | 30-JUL-15   | George  |
|  Grocery | 05-FEB-18   | Michael |
|  Produce | 30-JAN-18   | Joe     |
|  Grocery | 01-OCT-10   | Susan   |
|  Grocery | 25-SEP-17   | Sam     |    
|  Produce | 03-JUN-18   | Lizzy   |
|__________________________________|
```

The wanting result is the newest date joined from each dept:

```
 __________________________________
| DEPT     | DATE_JOINED | MANAGER |
|----------------------------------|
|  Grocery | 05-FEB-18   | Michael |
|  Produce | 03-JUN-18   | Lizzy   |
|__________________________________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date_joined = (select max(t2.date_joined) from t t2 where t2.dept = t.dept);
```

However, I have had good luck (performance-wise) with aggregation in this case:

```
select dept, max(date_joined) as date_joined,
       max(manager) keep (dense_rank first order by date_joined desc) as manager
from t
group by dept;
```